# How can I stop my vehicle after respawning

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict

var SpawnPoint : Transform;

function OnTriggerEnter(col : Collider)
{
if(col.tag =="Player")
{
    SpawnPoint.position = Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);


}

}
```

Can Anyone Help me? How can I stop my vehicle after respawning
because I pass through a death cube and respawn to the starting point but when I resume the game my vehicle is continue to move . I want to position it just like the position of the object at first !

Comment: Wait. You're asking for help to position you vehicle as your *object* or to stop moving? Anyway, it should have a velocity/speed - or something like that - property, right? You can't just set it to `0` on respawn?

Comment: Hm , it doesn't work I want that after respawning the car will instantly stop and when I control it again that is the time that It will move again

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rigidbody attached to your car, it has a velocity property so you can set that to `0`.

```
collider.gameobject.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3(0,0,0);
```

Comment: How do I implement it? please?